# How to export one file to NodeJS and ReactJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, object

I'm trying to export one object array file to nodeJS and ReactJS.

for example:

**config.js**

```
const config = {
  mode: "active", 
}
export default config;
```

I need to import this to the nodeJS file. At that time it's showing error on the export tag.

I tried this way:

```
    exports.config = {
      mode: "active", 
    }
    //export default config;
```

It's working on nodeJS. but I can't use this file to react. is there any possible way of using the same file for both.

NB: node version: v12.13.0

Comment: Try using ```import { config } from './config'``` to import the config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of using `exports.config`, you can access the config file by using

```
import { config } from './config`
```

In case you want to make the `config` as your default export just like in `export default config`, use `module.exports = config`

Comment: when  I'm using `module.exports = config` I can't access the object items from node and react.

Comment: Are you sure you are importing it right? Import it using ```import config from './config'``` and make sure to use ```module.exports = config```

Comment: Check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-grass-ps4u9?file=/src/index.js)